# Apache htdocs in folder with unicode name

Tags: php, apache, unicode, htdocs

I have my apache (for windows) htdocs in a folder like c:\anything1\怘怙怚怛\anything2. The problem is that in this case php won't execute any scripts from here and will display an error message like this:

`Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'c:/anything1/怘怙怚怛/anything2/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in Unknown on line 0
`

If I try to open a html file, it is served by apache, so it seems that the problem appears only with php.
Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hmm I like it.. good Question... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I'd say you can't do it without patching PHP. Apache (or the PHP apache handler) passes PHP a path encoded in UTF-8 and PHP ultimately relies on the ANSI version of FindFirstFile (and you cannot set a UTF-8 codepage).

I suggest you [submit a bug report](http://bugs.php.net/).

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem,
Read more @ http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2011/02/solve-php-failed-to-open-stream-error.html
it may be help you

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @Nilay I understand your point, but those solutions are not good for my situation, because I had to use the latest php and that specific unicode folder I mentioned in the question (or something very similar). But anyhow, thanks.