# PHP Unicode file name

Tags: php, .htaccess, unicode, filenames

PHP cannot handle a a file with Unicode characters: when I vist **testSite/главная.php** on my browser, it throws this error.

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'blah/blah/testSite/Ð³Ð»Ð°Ð²Ð½Ð°Ñ.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear\') in Unknown on line 0

However **testSite/главная.html** is fine.

Is there anyway that I can get around this or do I have to use a different programming language that handles Unicode better?

[Apache htdocs in folder with unicode name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856270/apache-htdocs-in-folder-with-unicode-name)

Comment: Using non plain ASCII file names, using space in file names is like asking for troubles. **ALWAYS**. Make yourself a favor and drop your bad habits.

Comment: I understand but I don't have the option to change the filenames. I gotta work with what I have.

Comment: It is not possible.

Here is the reason why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708017/can-a-php-file-name-or-a-dir-in-its-full-path-have-utf-8-characters/16941794#16941794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

Here is the thread explaining why

[Can a PHP file name (or a dir in its full path) have UTF-8 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708017/can-a-php-file-name-or-a-dir-in-its-full-path-have-utf-8-characters/16941794#16941794)

Answer (score 0):

Opening a php file with a unicode file name is **not** a `php` thing, but depends on the underlying operating system. As long as the OS supports unicode file names, it wil work.

On my debian squeeze this is not a problem at all, and windows 7 (where netbeans runs) creating a file named `главная.php` is without trouble:

```
include 'главная.php';
```

[image]

Comment: I have created the file, it is running it on the server where it fails

Comment: I am running it locally on winXP / xammp

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, your webserver uses win-1252 encoding for URIs.
Try to set utf-8 in your apache/nginx/whatever config.
If unicode names are used in require()/include() context only, you can also convert encoding with iconv()/mb_convert_encoding().

Comment: Then how come testSite/главная.html is okay?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "wfio://" in PHP5

https://github.com/kenjiuno/php-wfio

For folder access use fix:

.htaccess:

`php_value auto_prepend_file C:/fix.php`

fix.php:

```
$file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
if (!is_readable($file)) {
    $file="wfio://".$file;
                include $file;
                exit;
        }
```